# Недоступен домен (сайт) на территории РФ через HTTPS

Tags: nginx, debian, dns, domain

Доброго времени дня и ночи.

Столкнулся с довольно интересной проблемой, которую никак не могу решить (и даже не знаю в какую строну копать).

Есть домен на GoDaddy, есть сайт и хостинг, на хостинг передано управление DNS записью домена, так же есть суб-домен, который привязан к другому серверу. Для поддомена создана А запись с указанием нашего второго сервера. На сервере установлен Nginx, который обрабатывает запросы.

Основной сайт работает без нареканий, с ним проблем нет, но вот поддомен отказывается работать через HTTPS в России, при этом он доступен через HTTP (порт 80) и HTTPS (порт 443) из любой точки мира, но в России доступен исключительно по HTTP, HTTPS на порте 443 работать отказывается, просто не видно этот порт, словно он закрыт и/или недоступен.

На сервере не установлено никаких ограничений firewal, чистый Nginx.
В чем могла бы быть причина такого поведения работоспособности домена через HTTPS?

Comment: Поддомен: test.rivieragrouptravel.com